# I need the camel to filter the file based on tag value of XML file

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a XML file with tag `<ns:serviceName>`
I should pick the file only if serviceName is having value "enquiry"
My code is currently

```
from(file://path)
...
...


to(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the messages produced from the retrieved files like this:

```
Map<String, String> nsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
nsMap.put( "ns", "http://myuri.com" );

from("file://path")
.filter().xpath("ns:serviceName eq 'enquiry'", nsMap )
.to(url);
```

However, this will retrieve every file, and only process the ones that you are interested in.

If you are looking to *only retrieve* the files you want to process, and leave the others alone, I think you will need to implement a GenericFileFilter object and pass it to the Camel File2 component with the `filter` parameter. This is not something I've tried, and I suspect that you will end up having to read and parse the file, filter it, then read and parse it again in the route, which isn't going to be very efficient.